# Two site, one with https on IIS 7 problem

Tags: iis, iis-7, https

I have two domain on one ip in IIS. One of the sites bound to https. When in browser i add https to the first domain name, i open the second site, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using HTTP host headers here.

SSL doesn't support host headers so you'll need two IP addresses. One for the SSL site and one for the other site (which you can keep on using for non-ssl sites provided you keep using host headers).

Comment: Or you could use a different port, but you are absolutely right the SSL bindings are only based on IP/Port combination and host headers are not supported. This is because of a chicken and egg problem where the host header itself is encrypted in the SSL traffic and so cannot rely on it to find the certificate to decrypt it in the first place.